# How to perform missing primary key testing in data migration from RDBMS to Hive

Tags: hive, sqoop

Would you please guide in simple step by step way how to test primary key for each row to find any missing primary key while data migration from RDBMS to Hive table.Thank You!

Comment: Count the number of the primary keys in both RDBMS and Hive.

Comment: Thank you  inquisitive_mind for your reply.Do you mean suppose I have column id as primary key then I have to check by using query, 'select count(id) from table' in both hive and rdbms and match the count.Please confirm.